# mysql LIKE query takes too long

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

SQL :

```
        SELECT
            COUNT(usr.id) as `total_results`
        FROM
            users as usr
            LEFT JOIN profile as prof
                ON prof.uid = usr.uid
        WHERE
            usr.username LIKE '%a%'
            OR
            prof.name LIKE '%a%'
```

Indexes on users:

```
uid - uid
username - username
```

Indexes on profile

```
index1 - uid
index2 - uid,name
index3 - name
```

EXPLAIN :

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY     usr     ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    18387   
1   PRIMARY     prof    ref     index2,index1   index2  8   site.usr.uid    1   Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  sub     ref     i3,index1,index2    i3  16  site.usr.uid,const  1   Using index
```

the above query takes about 0.1221

how can i make it run faster?

Comment: remove the starting `%` on your `LIKE`s

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you genuinely trying to count all entries that have the letter "a" in either name or username?

Comment: @liquorvicar yes i am trying to get the count of search records

Comment: But what are you searching on? Whether a single letter is present in either field in any position? Whether either field starts with a single letter? Or might the search term be more than one letter? Please provide some realistic sample data and sample results.

Comment: well every possible search keyword, phrase and such... basically i am trying to get the database records where the keyword or prhase LIKE a username or a full name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed this query so it wont show the total result count when a search is done.

Seems a temporary solution or even permanent.

Answer (score 17):

The % at the beginning of the string to match makes it so that the indexes cannot be used.  A wildcard at the beginning nullifies the index and MySQL has to search within that column in *every* row.  It can't skip down.  If you **know** that the item you are searching for will be at the beginning of the beginning of the field, you can remove the beginning '%'.

However, if you are searching for 'steve', my answer will return 'steve', 'steven', 'steve-boss', but not 'boss-steve' or 'realsteve'.

Comment: so how other sites use search?is there a better method i could use?

Comment: @fxuser - Other sites don't just search a single character. Big sites like google don't use no relational databases that are specific to that kind of search. For this the best is full text index, but it does works different than just searching for a single char

Comment: @fxuser if you want to be search for all users that contain the character 'a' then there is no faster way in MySQL. You would have to upgrade your hardware or redesign your database. Honestly .1s for 18k records doesn't seem like that slow of a query either.

Comment: The problem comes when I want to get the count of records from the search... What if there are 5m of records in my search?it could take 10min to get the count and display it.

Comment: Scaling linearly that would take about 30 seconds. And the count portion is irrelevant really, not sure why you brought that up. The overwhelming majority of the time the query takes is scanning the entire table and checking your like conditions. Whether there are 5 matches or 5 million doesn't factor in that much here. Only the total number of records in the table.

Answer (score 7):

The initial `%` in your LIKE clauses means that the indexes for these columns cannot be used. I believe that the [MySQL full text index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) may do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

It uses indexes as much as it can (both primary keys for your left join). The main problem is LIKE '%a%', because in that case it cannot use index (if it was 'a%', it would be able to use index on username and name). What you can try (not sure if that will speed up things) is to use concat(usr.username, prof.name) like '%a%', but you will probably not notice any difference.

Full text index will not work, because full text index is useful when you search for a whole word.

Anyway, for the query you have your indexes on name and username are useless and just taking up space, so I would delete them. If LIKE 'a%' satisfies your need, then those indexes make sense.

If 'a%' doesn't satisfy your needs, you might take a look at other options, for example mysql query cache (if you expect frequent repetition of queries).

Comment: so do i do something wrong with this method that i use to search or there is nothing to speed up the things?cant believe there isnt any way...

Comment: As far as I know, no way to write it work faster and keep the same semantic.

Answer (score 0):

1) Buy a faster database server.

2) Redesign your database so that you don't have to look in two places for username or only allow users to search on one or the other

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, an index on a 'Value' field was slowing down selection when using the 'like' operator with a leading '%':

```
select distinct My_Value
from My_Table
where My_Value like '%a%';
```

If I removed the index, the same query ran quickly. But I needed the index for other situations.

In researching discovered the 'Ignore Index' command and rewrote the query and problem solved:

```
select distinct My_Value
from My_Table Ignore Index (My_Index)
where My_Value like '%a%';
```

More info on using 'Ignore Index': https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-hints.html