# Like Query in SQL taking time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

So I've looked around to try to find some posts on this and there are many 
[Like Query 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928929/mysql-like-query-takes-too-long) and [Like Query 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33302679/like-statement-taking-too-long) but none that address my specific question (that I could find).

I have two tables in which I have around 5000000+ records and I am returning Search result from these tables as :

```
    SELECT A.ContactFirstName, A.ContactLastName
    FROM   Customer.CustomerDetails AS A WITH (nolock)
    WHERE  (A.ContactFirstName + ' ' + A.ContactLastName LIKE '%' + 'a' + '%')
    UNION
    SELECT C.ContactFirstName, C.ContactLastName
    FROM   Customer.Contacts AS C WITH (nolock) 
    WHERE  (C.ContactFirstName + ' ' + C.ContactLastName LIKE '%' + 'a' + '%')
```

My problem is it is taking around 1 minute to execute.

For above query I am expecting result like :

[image: Expected Result]

Please suggest me the best practice to improve performance. Thanks in advance.

**NOTE** : No missing Indexes.

Comment: please show an example of the input data and the expected results

Comment: please provide the query plan (EXPLAIN).

Comment: Why do you need the second part of the `UNION`? Every result should already be contained in the first part since `%` also matches zero characters. Apart from that I guess you are out of luck because your like-condition is not indexable...

Comment: `mysql` _or_ `sql-server`?

Comment: Edited and added required information

Comment: your result set is not the result of your query because UNION discard duplicated rows but you have MARK WEILER twice

Comment: You might find [some useful information here](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/10/searching-strings-sql-server-expensive/).

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/06/sargable-why-string-is-slow/

Answer (score 0):

when you use  "LIKE '%xxx%'" index are not used that why your query is slow i think. When you use "LIKE 'xxx%')" index is used (if an index exist on column of course. >Other proble you do a like on concatenante column, i dont knwo if index is used in this case. And why do a 'xxx' + ' ' + 'yyy' like 'z%', just do 'xxx' like 'z%' its the same. You can try to modify your query like this

```
SELECT A.ContactFirstName, A.ContactLastName
FROM   Customer.CustomerDetails AS A WITH (nolock)
WHERE  A.ContactFirstName LIKE '%a%' or A.ContactLastName LIKE '%a%'
UNION
SELECT C.ContactFirstName, C.ContactLastName
FROM   Customer.Contacts AS C WITH (nolock) 
WHERE  C.ContactFirstName LIKE 'a%'
```

Comment: I have a feeling that the first query might be even worse performing. Since it has to check two columns for `a`'s instead of one.

Comment: merging two columns and then check strings would lead to long process tho - @RaduGheorghiu

Comment: if he has an index on one or two column no sur

Comment: @RushabhMaster Same as Breaking down each word in two columns and checking it for `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Charindex which improves performance of the search ,Here it checks the string to match with first charcter of given search charecter and doesn't search for any more matches.

```
DECLARE @Search VARCHAR(10)='a'
SELECT A.ContactFirstName, A.ContactLastName
    FROM   Customer.CustomerDetails AS A WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE  CHARINDEX(@Search,(A.ContactFirstName + ' ' + A.ContactLastName),0)>1
```